# Tracking a file in a dataframe and put the location in another column with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
    file name           folder 1              folder 2                folder 3            
0     1.txt        2021-05-11 14:04:30    2021-05-11 15:04:30      2021-05-11 16:04:30
1     2.txt        2021-05-12 14:04:30    2021-05-12 15:04:30            NaN
2     3.txt        2021-05-13 14:04:30            NaN                    NaN
```

So, I have some files and I registered the timestamps when they moved in another folder. Basically, what i want is to create another column in this dataframe name "location of the file", so if the last timestamp is in the specific folder, put the folder name in the new column. The desirable output would look like this one:

```
  file name         folder 1              folder 2               folder 3        Location of the file
0   1.txt     2021-05-11 14:04:30   2021-05-11 15:04:30    2021-05-11 16:04:30    file is in folder 3
1   2.txt     2021-05-12 14:04:30   2021-05-12 15:04:30          NaN              file is in folder 2         
2   3.txt     2021-05-13 14:04:30          NaN                   NaN              file is in folder 1
```

EDIT:

Hey @Andrej, in my real scenario I have some columns between folder 1 and file name, like the one I put there that tells the file type. If I use your solution then the location for the file 4.xlsx with be print like this dataframe below:

```
  file name  filetype   .. folder 1              ..  folder 3           Loc. of file
0   1.txt      txt      .. 2021-05-11 14:04:30   ..  2021-05-11 16:04:30 file is in folder 3
1   2.txt      txt      .. 2021-05-12 14:04:30   ..     NaN              file is in folder 2
2   3.txt      txt      .. 2021-05-13 14:04:30   ..     NaN              file is in folder 3
3   4.xlsx     xlsx     ..   NaN                 ..     NaN              file is in filetype
```

Can i just somehow get the location of the file only from the column "folder 1", "folder 2" and "folder 3". And if there is no timestamp in folder 1, put NaN in the "Location of the file" column, like this df below:

```
  file name  filetype   .. folder 1              ..  folder 3           Loc. of file
0   1.txt      txt      .. 2021-05-11 14:04:30   ..  2021-05-11 16:04:30 file is in folder 3
1   2.txt      txt      .. 2021-05-12 14:04:30   ..     NaN              file is in folder 2
2   3.txt      txt      .. 2021-05-13 14:04:30   ..     NaN              file is in folder 3
3   4.xlsx     xlsx     ..   NaN                 ..     NaN                NaN
```

Comment: Hi @user14073111 Do you assume the 3 folders are placed in timestamp order ?  That's is, all files placed in folder3 are of later timestamp than those placed in the other 2 folders ?  If yes, it's fine.  Otherwise, you have to reconsider the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
df["Location of the file"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: "File is in {}".format(x.index[x.notna()][-1]),
    axis=1,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  file name             folder 1             folder 2             folder 3 Location of the file
0     1.txt  2021-05-11 14:04:30  2021-05-11 15:04:30  2021-05-11 16:04:30  File is in folder 3
1     2.txt  2021-05-12 14:04:30  2021-05-12 15:04:30                  NaN  File is in folder 2
2     3.txt  2021-05-13 14:04:30                  NaN                  NaN  File is in folder 1
```

---

EDIT: To handle all `NaN`:

```py
df["Location of the file"] = df.loc[:, "folder 1":].apply(
    lambda x: "File is in {}".format(x.index[x.notna()][-1])
    if not x.isna().all()
    else np.nan,
    axis=1,
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  file name             folder 1             folder 2             folder 3 Location of the file
0     1.txt  2021-05-11 14:04:30  2021-05-11 15:04:30  2021-05-11 16:04:30  File is in folder 3
1     2.txt  2021-05-12 14:04:30  2021-05-12 15:04:30                  NaN  File is in folder 2
2     3.txt                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN                  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Adrejkesely

Comment: Clever answer @Andrej

Comment: Hey @Adrejkesely, I edited my question, can you please check? (sorry for always editing my questions)

Comment: @user14073111 Updated my answer.

Comment: @AndrejKesely thanks a lot man, you are helping me so much

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) on `axis=1` (column index) to get the index label of the element with maximum datetime values, and text concat. with 'file is in ' to get the new column contents, as follows:

```
df['Location of the file'] = 'file is in ' + df.iloc[:, 1:].idxmax(axis=1)
```

**Note that this solution does not assume folder1, folder2, folder3 are created in time sequence (folder3 later than folder2 and folder1). It works so long as the 3 columns contain datetime fields which can be compared of to get the latest time.**

Result:

```
print(df)

  file name            folder 1            folder 2            folder 3 Location of the file
0     1.txt 2021-05-11 14:04:30 2021-05-11 15:04:30 2021-05-11 16:04:30  file is in folder 3
1     2.txt 2021-05-12 14:04:30 2021-05-12 15:04:30                 NaT  file is in folder 2
2     3.txt 2021-05-13 14:04:30                 NaT                 NaT  file is in folder 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @SeaBean

Comment: @user14073111  Will take a look.  Anyway, I would like to make sure that folder3 will always take the latest timestamp among the 3 folders if all not NaN, is that right ? There is no choice that folder2 will get later timestamp than folder3 when both are filled with datetimes, right ?